# How is it true? if a polynomial has no solutions then it is irreducable.

Tags: linear-algebra

So I found this statement in my friend's notes and I think it's wrong for example if $x^2 + 1 = 0$ has no solution and is not reducable but if I square the whole thing then it is reducable but still would not have any solitions. what's wrong with my logic here. Thanks.

Comment: you are correct. A less obvious example is $x^4 + 4$ which factors nicely as two quadratics

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: You're right. A small point of terminology: polynomials have **roots** and equations have **solutions**. A root of $p(x)$ is a solution of the equation $p(x) = 0$. So your question should read "... a polynomial with no roots is irreducible", which as you have concluded correctly is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a wrong statement. For example,
$$x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$
A correct statement would be -" If a polynomial has no roots then it cannot be reduced in linear factors".

Or more generally," If a polynomial has no roots then it cannot be reduced in polynomial having roots".

Because $p(x)=q(x)g(x)\ ,\ q(k)=0\Longrightarrow p(k)=0$

Hope it helps